# Pass a string from child component to parent component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am very new, so please excuse my beginner questions… How would I pass a simple string of text from a child component to a parent component in React with JSX? I tried the following, but it doesn't work:
(Thanks for your help!)

Now fixed and it works!…

//child component

```
function ChildData() {
    return (
        <p>
            Here's the Child Data
        </p>
    );
}
export default ChildData;
```

//parent component

```
import ChildData from './ChildData';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildData />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a difference between `passing` data from a child to a parent and just `rendering` the child component.

In your case, it seems like you want to just render the data of the child component which you can do by calling it as a `component`

```
function childDataText() {
  return (
    <p>A String of Text</p>
  );
}

export default childDataText
```

```
import ChildData from './ChildData';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildData/> {/* calling the child component to render */}
    </div>
  );

}
```